# On Dreamhost, how can I get "django-admin startproject" to correctly set up a project in the way django 1.4 is supposed to?

Tags: django, dreamhost

I'm hosting my website on Dreamhost and I've actually managed to get django working for the most part. The one thing I'm still struggling with is to get django-admin to behave like the version from 1.4 instead of 1.2 (which is what dreamhost runs). I set up a virtualenv and such following these instructions http://blog.oscarcp.com/?p=167 . Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If it's running 1.2, it will set things up like 1.2. If you want the 1.4 structure, you'll have to install 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not entering into your virtualenv before you run django-admin. What does `django-admin.py --version` say?